# How to make link unclickable using CSS or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML.

```
<ul class="static">
    <li class="static dynamic-children">
        <a class="static dynamic-children menu-item" href="test.php" tabindex="0">
            <span class="additional-background">
                <span class="menu-item-text">Link</span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dynamic">
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see when I click on "Link" then it takes me to "test.php" page. I want this "Link" to be unclickable like you place "#" for e.g. href="#"

Is it possible to do this using CSS or Jquery? Can't use Javascript's **document.getElementById** because there is no ID defined for this element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different options:

```
$('a[href="test.php"]').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

or

```
$("static dynamic-children a.menu-item").click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

You can also use [**event.preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) which prevents the default/expected behaviour of a link. Use like:

```
$("static dynamic-children a.menu-item").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Write `return false`

```
$("a.menu-item").click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

OR

`e.preventDefault()`

```
$("a.menu-item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the link behavior by firing `preventDefault()` on the click of this link:

```
$("a.menu-item").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to add some explanation @dcodesmith. A bunch of code pasted from nowhere isn't pedagogical.

Comment: @MaximeLorant You beat me to it, I wanted to post the solution and then elaborate on it. Cheers ;